# knitr: Using subscript with fig.cap in Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

How do I go about including subscript in a figure caption when using `{r fig.cap=""}`?

Mock .Rmd file:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
````

````
```{r fig.cap = "CO2 Concentration", echo = FALSE}
plot(rnorm(100))
````

I would like to get the 2 in CO2 in subscript. Is `fig.cap` the best way, or is something better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use standard [Markdown syntax](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/markdown-syntax.html)

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

This is ^superscript^  
This is ~subscript~

```{r fig.cap = 'CO~2~ Concentration', echo = FALSE}
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

[image]